# Show only not None values in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a `Model` with numerous attributes; in the template rendered by my `DetailView` I want to show only the attributes that are not `None`.

This can be easily done with an `if` template tag that checks if the value of the attribute is not `None`, tho I should add an if condition for every attribute in my model, and there's a lot of them.

I would like to iterate through all the attributes and `if not None` display them.
In pseudo code it would look like this:

```
{% for attribute in my_instance.all_attributes %}
  {% if attribute.value is not None %}
    {{attribute.value}}
```

I can get a tuple of concrete attributes both through the class or the instance:

```
cls._meta.concrete_fields
```

or

```
self._meta.concrete_fields
```

Now that I have the `my_instance.all_attributes` in my pseudo code example, I can iterate it but I don't know how to get the actual value of the instance's attribute.

EDIT:

`.concrete_values` returns an array of `Field` instances, it looks like this:

```
(<django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: gov>, <django.db.models.fields.BooleanField: in_group>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: legal_class>,)
```

I can access the value of the name attribute of the `Field` instance using `.name`. Calling `.name` on the example above would return `'gov'`, `'in_group'`, `'legal_class'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors of Django went out of their way to make sure that the template language isn't used to do things like this! Their opinion as I understand it  is that templates should do formatting, and Python should do program logic.

There are two ways around it. One is to create a structure that the template can iterate through, and pass it to the DetailView context. Something like

```
def get_context_data(self):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    fieldnames = [
        x.name for x in self.object._meta.concrete_fields ]
    display_fields = [
        (name, getattr( self.object, name, None)) for name in fieldnames ]
    display_fields = [ x for x in display_fields if x[1] is not None ]

    data['display_fields'] = display_fields
    return data
```

and in the template you can now do

```
{% for name,value in display_fields %}
```

You might prefer to code a list of names instead of using `._meta.concrete_fields` because that lets you choose the order in which they appear. Or you could start with an ordered list and append anything that's in the _meta but not yet in your list (and delete anything that's in your list but not in  _meta)

The other way is to use Jinja as the template engine for this view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks very promising. I'm aware that heavy logic should be placed in the view layer and not in the template, in fact 'getattr( self.object, name, None)' seems exactly was I was looking for. Gonna test real quick. I was wondering if the value was accessible from the Field instance like name is.